# Is it reasonable to use modern OpenGL context?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

Recently I've used some features that require modern OpenGL context (specifically ARB_debug_output requires to create context with WGL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB via wglCreateContextAttribs) and encountered several implications (glew failed to gather extension with modern context, I've encountered several implications integrating new context into wx widgets). So the evident questions occur:

- **Is it reasonable to use modern opengl context?**
- **Are there many features that can't be used with older context via extensions?**
- **Is modern context faster?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follow is just my considerations after using an OpenGL 3.3 *core profile* context for a while:

---

**Is it reasonable to use modern opengl context?**

It depends. There are a multitude of libraries and middleware that still do not support *wglCreateContextAttribs* and the like, but some are open/small enough that you can just get to the code and change what you need.

Personally I find the lack of "deprecated" functions a blessing, because one can focus on the juicy gpu hardware capabilities of our era.

If you are writing a sort of middleware, where you have to support most of OpenGL functionality, then using a "modern" context is more than a blessing: it is a life-saver.

---

**Are there many features that can't be used with older context via extensions?**

Pratically no, as long as the hardware is the same. However the number of extensions is so great that there are probably plenty of corner cases.

---

**Is modern context faster**

Surely it can't be slower.